# My Tkinter label dissapeared when i put in the buttons

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.4

I am trying to create a simple hangman game using tkinter with python. While creating the GUI, the first thing I put in were the dashes.`lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text= xhash)`. When I put in my buttons, the label disappeared. I have tried making the window bigger, but it still didn't come back.

Here is my full code:

```
#importing modules
import tkinter
import random

#creating the dashes 
f = open(r'C:\Users\Gareth\Documents\hangman\words.txt', 'r') 
word = f.readlines()
guess = random.choice(word)
hash = []
xhash = ""
while len(hash) < len(str(guess)):
    hash.append('_ ')
def rejoin():
    xhash = "".join(hash)
    xhash.strip("[]")
    xhash.strip(",")
    xhash.strip("'")

#creating the window
window = tkinter.Tk()
window.minsize(300, 300)

#commands for buttons a-z
def acmd():
    for i in list(guess):
        if i == 'a':
            hash[guess.index(i)] = 'a'
            rejoin()
            lbl.configure(text= xhash)
    abtn.configure(bg = 'red')

#label
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text= xhash)

#buttons for letters a-z
abtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'a', command = acmd)
bbtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'b')
cbtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'c')
dbtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'd')...

#placing lbl and buttons
lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
abtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 1)
bbtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 2)
cbtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 3)...
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Did you position your buttons?

Comment: Can you please post more of your code? How are you positioning them?

Comment: `lbl.pack()
                      abtn.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
                      bbtn.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
                        cbtn.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)
                    dbtn.pack(side = tkinter.LEFT)`

Comment: Check my answer below , you can use grid to position them correctly .

Comment: is that enough, or do you need more? @AnandSKumar

Comment: i did that, but it still wont do right: http://i.imgur.com/WvDENiF.png

Comment: I just gave an example , you have to think which row and column to give , try giving row =1 for the buttons.

Comment: ive been playing around with the nubers, but it doesnt move much, and it hasnt worked yet... `lbl.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
abtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 1)
bbtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 2)
cbtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 3)
dbtn.grid(row = 3 , column = 4)`

Comment: Can you try putting them a little more far? Maybe difference of 10 for each ?

Comment: The whole code could be useful, note that you can't mix `.pack()` and `.grid()` so if you have used `.pack()` somewhere else replace it

Comment: @VRage: be careful with that advice: you can mix them in the same program, but you can't mix them with the same parent widget.

Comment: This question doesn't have enough information for us to be able to help you. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BryanOakley well according to his screenshot it looks like he just has only one parent. But yeah you are right. If you attach a wrong parent you are lost in Tkinter.

Comment: Here is a link to the code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hPXPTlho6o4BAsw92k29Tb0KyNHCODnphMrz1cQTaZ0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: is that enough @BryanOakley

Comment: @Gareth: no, the relevant code needs to be part of the question.

Comment: @BryanOakley I would love to, but it always says its not properly formatted, no matter what i try... ill put the link in the question but thats about as much as i can do...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem did not lie within the label, but within the text.

`def rejoin():
    xhash = "".join(hash)
    xhash.strip("[]")
    xhash.strip(",")
    xhash.strip("'")`
the only adjustment needed was a global statement...
without that, whatever was done in the function had nothing to do with anything else, so, the previously assigned xhash = '', was simply left blank...

Answer (score 0):

You would need to position them correctly, most probably either you are not positioning them or positioning them on top of each other. You would need to use [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) to position them

Example -

```
lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text= xhash)
lbl.grid(row=0,column=1)
abtn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'a', command = acmd)
abtn.grid(row=0,column=2)
```

Comment: You do not _need_ to use `grid` to solve this problem. It may provide a work-around, but it won't solve the core problem.